# Guarantee one and only one instance of Google App Engine possible?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

Once an App Engine instance is spun up, you are billed 15 minutes. If it goes idle, it'll shutdown and Google will spin up a new instance, billed, again, for 15 minutes. You can easily rack up 4.5 instance hours with 18 HTTP requests.

I am wondering if there's any method to keep one and only one App engine instance alive and prevent it from going idle. Preferably, I'm look for a cost-free approach. Thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities when talking about App Engine, you have either the standard or the flexible environments. This documentation helps you [choose between the standard or the flexible environments](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#comparing_high-level_features).

Once you know that, if you are using App Engine standard, you must configure the kind of escalation you wish, which can be [manual, automatic or basic](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_types). According to that, you can [configure your `app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#scaling_elements) file with your desired setting. For example, you would like to have `manual_scaling` and set `instances` to 1. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_types):

> Manual scaling uses resident instances that continuously run the specified number of instances irrespective of the load level. This allows tasks such as complex initializations and applications that rely on the state of the memory over time.

In case you are using App Engine flex, here is all the documentation to [configure the escalation settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#services). Again, for your case, you would want to set `automatic_scaling` and `min_number_instances` to 1 (since default value is 2) and `max_number_instances` to 1.

In terms of billing concerns, [you are only billed for the amount of instances you specify in the configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_billing) mentioned above.

I strongly recommend you to read though the documentation in the links provided to know more details about this.

Comment: Even if I set the `min` and `max` number instance to 1, the instance can still idle out and terminate at which point a new instance will have to spin up. I was looking for a solution to constantly send requests (say at 1 minute intervals) to the instance so that the instance doesn't idle out.

Comment: I updated my answer. I also thought about what you are proposing, but it seems like it would be an unnecessary effort to be performing this periodical requests only to keep it from going idle. With manual scaling, your one instance should always be ready to respond requests, hence not going idle.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Quick question. If I wanted to periodically request an App Engine instance, would using Cloud Scheduler to trigger a simple Cloud Function cron job work?

Comment: You can use several products for that purpose, but as you would want this endpoint to be called periodically, I believe the easier way would be either to set a [cron job](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) or [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules). Cloud Function is not needed here.